# Where are TextEdit files that are not moved to iCloud Drive stored?

Tags: macos, icloud, folders, textedit

After upgrading to Yosemite I did not migrate to iCloud Drive and iCloud text files were in a local folder which was very difficult to locate.

I can't find these files now. They were in a folder that had a long "com.open" or similar name.

Comment: Did you save them in the cloud before, or why were they in such a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't migrated to iCloud Documents then they are still stored in the iCloud Documents folder in

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com.apple.textedit/
```

Comment: I did not migrate but they were removed in an upgrade. I found them using Timecapsule backup.